# Fantasy book series with a school for magical hero children

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel, magical-creatures

I read one book from a book series while I was in primary school over a decade ago.

There was a school of kids in a fantasy world of monsters and a trio of these kids go on a quest to save their school/world from danger.

Along the way in order to obtain a critical item/power they must each sacrifice the thing they treasure most in the world. For the girl this is her beauty and she gets turned into a toad woman. For one of the boys it’s his friendship with the protagonist and a giant toad woman is summoned to wipe all his memories of the protagonist with a kiss.

I think the main character could use portal magic and fought with a sword.

I don’t remember what force of evil they were fighting but eventually they win. The protagonist is able to find the toad woman again and convince her to restore his friend’s memories of him (she fancies him, so it doesn’t take much convincing) and the trio eventually return to the castle where their school is.

I can’t remember the book or series title, or the characters names, just these details.

If anyone recognises what book this is from PLEASE tell me, I haven’t been able to find it for years.

Comment: From the preview i was ready to suggest the percy jackson series but the toad woman rules that out